# Wireless and Internet settings disappeared from system settings

Tags: settings, internet, release-juno

Has anyone encountered the problem where clicking network settings from the applet just shows the System settings window? I can't access wireless or hotspot settings. [image]

Comment: i connected my laptop to the internet via ethernet cable, ran the AppCenter, updated some drivers and wifi appeared after rebooting.

Comment: Same problem with sound settings...

Answer (score 0):

Run this command line

```
sudo apt install switchboard-plug-networking
```

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information so that it is simple enough for someone with zero technical knowledge to easily understand.